# Как сделать рисунки из символов

Tags: алгоритм, golang, рисование

Пользователь вводит ширину и высоту рисунка (к примеру прямоугольник), а программа его рисует. К примеру :

Ширина = 5, высота = 3.

```
ффффф
ффффф
ффффф
```

Первая часть кода готова, дальше не понимаю как написать.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Эта программа рисует фигуру по введёным параметрам")
    fmt.Println()

    var choise uint
    fmt.Print("Выберете тип фигуры:") 
    fmt.Println("1) Прямоугольник")
    fmt.Println("2) Ромб")
    fmt.Print("Фигура:")
    fmt.Scan(&choise)

    if choise == 1 {
        var w, h uint

        fmt.Print("Ведите ширину прямоугольника:  ")
        fmt.Scan(&w)
        fmt.Println()

        fmt.Print("Введите высоту прямоугольника:  ")
        fmt.Scan(&h)
        fmt.Println()   
    }
}
```

Comment: Ты собираешься рисовать прямоугольниками?

Comment: Пока что да... Потом собираюсь добавить ромб, что видно в коде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Коллега, вам не хватает примерно этого (только для квадратов):

```
    func square () {
        for t := 0; t < 10; t++ {
                for i := 0 ; i < 10; i++ {
                        fmt.Print ("@")
                }
                fmt.Println()
        }
    }
```